# Is there a Phython function to print exactly one two returned values?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do something like the code shows:

```
def function():
    return 5, 6

print(function()[0]) #Is there a possibility to do this?
```

NOT:

```
a, b = function()
print(a)
```

I expect the output of 5.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to specify a bitter better what you would like to achieve. `print(function()[0])` does print `5`, so it is a bit unclear what you are after. Perhaps [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) could help you.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine

Comment: And its working the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well. _ is a temp variable

```
a, _ = function()
print(a)
```

The readability for this is better is my 2 cents.